# How to modify sanitize_user WordPress function to accept user name in cyrillic

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, cyrillic, sanitize

Original function:

```
function sanitize_user( $username, $strict = false ) {
$raw_username = $username;
$username     = wp_strip_all_tags( $username );
$username     = remove_accents( $username );
// Kill octets.
$username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
// Kill entities.
$username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username );

// If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
if ( $strict ) {
    $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
}

$username = trim( $username );
// Consolidate contiguous whitespace.
$username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

/**
 * Filters a sanitized username string.
 *
 * @since 2.0.1
 *
 * @param string $username     Sanitized username.
 * @param string $raw_username The username prior to sanitization.
 * @param bool   $strict       Whether to limit the sanitization to specific characters.
 */
return apply_filters( 'sanitize_user', $username, $raw_username, $strict );
```

I want to modify it to accept user name in cyrillic (Serbian) when user perform registration.

Serbian Cyrillic Alphabet
абвгдђежзијклљмнњопрстћуфхцчџшАБВГДЂЕЖЗИЈКЛЉМНЊОПРСТЋУФХЦЧЏШ

Answer (score 0):

```
function mujuonly_sanitize_user( $username, $raw_username, $strict ) {

    $username    = wp_strip_all_tags( $raw_username );
    $username    = remove_accents( $username );

    // Kill octets
    $username    = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
    $username    = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username ); // Kill entities
    // If strict, reduce to ASCII and Cyrillic characters for maximum portability.
    if ( $strict )
        $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-zа-я0-9 _.\-@]|iu', '', $username );

    $username = trim( $username );

    // Consolidate contiguous whitespace
    $username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

    return $username;
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'mujuonly_sanitize_user', 10, 3 );
```

Try this - **Tested OK with WP 5.6**

Comment: This will return an error: Error: This username is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username.

Comment: Tried with this символов successfully

Comment: The following won't let it go through `чџшАБВГДЂЕ`

Comment: Thanks for response. I think your code is for Russian alphabet. Serbian is а-ш А-Ш

Comment: It works for WP and other plugins but I stll have problem with Peepso plugin. It wont accept registration with user name in cyrillic. But if I change it later in database to cyrilic I am able to login. I think problem is with registration form/validation.